# can't access value from inside then to outside then Promise

Tags: angular6

I'm trying to get value from inside to outside then using promise.

In my controller I have:

```
async Sample(userId: number)
  {
      let data = this.userService.getAffectedExpertisesPromise(userId);
      await data.then((uri) =>
      {
          uri.forEach((exp: Expertise) =>
          {
              this.empList.push(exp.name);
          });
      })

      return this.empList;
  }
```

On **ngOnInit**, I call this function:

```
this.Sample(25).then(item =>
                    {
                        item.forEach((expLibelle: String) =>
                        {
                            listExp.push(expLibelle);
                        });
                        console.log("------------------------ List Size Inside: " + listExp.length);
                    });

      console.log("------------------------ List Size Outside : " + listExp.length);
```

In **service user** file, I have:

```
getAffectedExpertisesPromise(id: number): Promise<any>
    {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/expertisesObj/${id}`).toPromise();
    }
```

It produces:

> ------------------------ List Size Outside : 0
>
> ------------------------ List Size Inside: 3

As you saw:

- the size inside `then` is 3 --> Correct answer
- the size inside `then` is 0 --> Wrong answer

Could you please help me solving that issue ?.

Big thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not trying using `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:6227/api/auth/users', false);  
request.send(null);
```

HTH.

Comment: Hello Miss @SariaEssid. that works as well. Big Thank.